# How to implement Counting Sort to sort an array of char in C?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, counting-sort

So, I'm trying to implement the Counting Sort algorithm to sort an array of digits given by the user, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n=15;
    char arr[]={"ABEFGEAGCEDBFAC"}; //I'm using this string to test it out
    /*for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Insert a letter %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    */
    printf("Array: \n[ ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(i<n-1)
            printf("%c | ",arr[i]);
        if(i==n-1)
            printf("%c ]\n",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int range[7];
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        range[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){ //I've seen other ways to do this, but I just need it to go from A-G
                        //not sure if this is the problem.
        switch(arr[i]){
            case 'A':
                range[0]++;
                break;
            case 'B':
                range[1]++;
                break;
            case 'C':
                range[2]++;
                break;
            case 'D':
                range[3]++;
                break;
            case 'E':
                range[4]++;
                break;
            case 'F':
                range[5]++;
                break;
            case 'G':
                range[6]++;
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("Counting array (number of times it appear in the array): \n[ ");
    for(i=0; i<7; i++){
        if(i<6)
            printf("%d | ",range[i]);
        if(i==6)
            printf("%d ]\n",range[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=1;i<7;i++){ //Here I do the sum of all elements in the array
        range[i] = range[i] + range[i-1];
    }

    printf("Sum of the array: \n[ ");
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        if(i<6)
            printf("%d | ",range[i]);
        if(i==6)
            printf("%d ]\n",range[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    char ord[15];

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        ord[--range[arr[i] - 'A']] = arr[i];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%c ",ord[i]);
    }
/*
    printf("Ord: \n[ ");
    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        if(i<14)
            printf("%c | ",ord[i]);
        if(i==14)
            printf("%c ]\n",ord[i]);
    }
*/
}
```

So, as you can see, if I'm not wrong, the error is when I try to put each letter in its correct position using the range array in the second to last *for* sentence. I've seen other ways to implement it but I just can't get it done, it's crashing as soon as I try to print ord[i].
I'm having trouble trying to fully understand what's going on in that *for*.

**Update:**
Tried to implement fish-404's corrections on the code as shown above. Can't get it properly implemented.
**Last Update:**
Code above is now finished and fully functional. Thanks to @fish-404 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, `arr[i]` is a char, you try to use char as the array `range` index.

```
ord[range[arr[i]]] = arr[i];
```

---

**Update**

If I get you correctly, I think you want use the `arr[i]` char as a index to search in `range` array.

As you can see, the `range` array you use count the letter, to use the letter to index, you just use `arr[i]-'A'` to count the letter order in the `range` array.

```cpp
for (i = n; i >= i; i--)
  ord[--range[arr[i] - 'A']] = arr[i];

// use this to see result
for (i = n;i >= 1; i--)
  printf("i: %d, ord[i]: %c\n", i, ord[i-1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, as I was studying this line I figured it out too! :).

Comment: I have to ask if you know how can I implement it?. range is an array of ints so it can store the index position where each letter has to be in place in the final array, so how can I use it to order *ord* ?

Comment: @Chriss Hi, I update the anwser, see if what you want.

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble trying to implement your corrections. Updated the main question.

Comment: @Chriss Hi, after `char odr[15]`, you just nedd use the statement I post above to test, you don't need the orginal other statements.

Comment: You are totally correct, just as you responded with this comment I was trying to figured out and worked.
Thank you very much!!!